# Plugging 3.5" SATA drives into SAS ports on Proliant G6 DL360 Server

Tags: hard-drive, sata

So I've got an HP Proliant G6 Dl360 that I'm hoping to run Freenas on from a VM. Has plenty of RAM (32GB), Processing Power, etc. Problem is storage. I have 5 WD 4TB 3.5" Hard drives I could use but I have no idea how to plug them in.

The server has the HP DG146BB976 2.5" SAS hard drives in there right now, connection on it looks like this right now hooked up to SAS.

[image]

One thought I had was to simply buy an enclosure for the drives like this one ([KingWin 5.25" Tray-Less SATA Mobile Rack for 5 x 3.5" HDD (MKS-535TL)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BMJ1WD6)) since it has a cable for each individual drive, power them through the enclosure, then just get some kind of cable converter from SATA to SAS and plug them in.

I’ve read that not using HP drives on Proliant can be finicky but I thought if I just get the cable and test one hard drive on it then I can see if it would work.

- Any thoughts on this?
- What cable would I get to create this connection?
- Better way to do it? PCI express card with SATA ports?

I found a SAS 29 Pin Female to SATA III 22 Pin Male Cable on Amazon that is on the right track I believe (first review says he was able to plug in his 3.5" drives externally to his DL380 G5) but wouldn't the SATA connection have to be female in order to have it work in my case? The hard drive is the WD40EFRX in case that helps.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I ended up just using a spare computer that I had with Windows and using it as a NAS. Thanks for reminding me of this though. I've got some extra cash now and some spare time coming up so I might break down and buy the cable to see how it goes. I'll reply again if I get it going.

Comment: I've heard from plenty of people, that you can use these kind of SATA extension cables and it works fine: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/22-Pin-7-15-Male-to-Female-Serial-ATA-SATA-Data-Power-Combo-Extension-Cable-UK/253282919378

Comment: It worked!!!! Bought a 5 drive enclosure and a couple of mini-sas to sata cables and just plugged it directly into the port inside it. For some dumb reason I thought I could plug it into the front where the hard drives go but that was a mistake, but still ultimately worked out by unplugging the connections from the backplane. I really appreciate it @MortenMoulder for reminding me of this. Now I can build up this thing and virtualize a ton of stuff and get a bit deeper into studying.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the confirmation. I ended up grabbing a bunch of SATA extension cables with power+data and they work flawlessly. Simply plug them into the front of the server (where the 2.5" HDDs would go) and plug the other end into the HDD!